# Replace Asynchronous Anonymous Class with Function

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am thinking this may be possible with the shapeless library.

I'm using the shapeless to convert an anonymous class to a closure. This requires the use of `hlisted` from the `FnHListerAux` trait.

All I want to do is get rid of the dummy function passed in and return a closure around this function which has the same type signature as `F`. This would be easy if there wasn't an asynchronously executed anonymous class. Is there a way to get around this?

```
def async[F, A <: HList, R](
  shell: Shell,
  success: F,
  failure: FunctionTypes.Failure,
  dummy: F)(implicit h: FnHListerAux[F, A => R],
            u: FnUnHListerAux[A => R, F]): F =
{ (args: A) =>

  require(shell != null, "Shell cannot be null")
  require(shell.getDisplay() != null, "The shell must have a display")

  val display = shell.getDisplay()
  display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    def run(): Unit = {
      try {
        success.hlisted(args)
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          failure(e)
      }
    }
  })

  dummy.hlisted(args)
}.unhlisted
```

Comment: There must be some serious problems with your algorithm if you need senseless stuff like that. Try to explain what you need that for.

Comment: Sure, that'd be a good idea. I'm very new to Scala. I'm still very curious to see if you could actually replace the body of a function. However, for my actual problem, the solution would most likely lie in the shapeless library, which is way above my level of knowledge and I'm still trying to understand its very nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start by simplifying a bit. Suppose I have a function `f`. I don't know it's arity in advance, and I don't care about what it returns. I want to wrap it with some functionality and get a function with the same argument types. I also don't care what this resulting function returns, so I may as well have it return `Unit`.

You could write a bunch (well, 22) of functions like the following:

```
def wrap[A](f: A => Unit): A => Unit = ???
def wrap[A, B](f: (A, B) => Unit): (A, B) => Unit = ???
def wrap[A, B, C](f: (A, B, C) => Unit): (A, B, C) => Unit = ???
```

But you don't want to.

Shapeless can definitely help you solve this problem more generically:

```
def wrap[F, A <: HList](f: F)(
  implicit h: FnHListerAux[F, A => Unit], u: FnUnHListerAux[A => Unit, F]
): F = { (args: A) =>
  println("Before!"); f.hlisted(args); println("After!")
}.unhlisted
```

Which gives us:

```
scala> def f(i: Int, s: String) { println(s * i) }
f: (i: Int, s: String)Unit

scala> val wf = wrap(f _)
wf: (Int, String) => Unit = <function2>

scala> wf(3, "ab")
Before!
ababab
After!
```

Note that `f` could return something other than `Unit` and this would still work, since everything in Scala is a `Unit` and the `FunctionN` traits are covariant in their return type.

Applying this approach to your code, we get the following:

```
def async[F, A <: HList](
  shell: Shell, success: F, failure: FunctionTypes.Failure
)(
  implicit h: FnHListerAux[F, A => Unit], u: FnUnHListerAux[A => Unit, F]
): F = { (args: A) =>
  require(shell != null, "Shell cannot be null")
  require(shell.getDisplay() != null, "The shell must have a display")

  val display = shell.getDisplay()
  display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    def run(): Unit = {
      try {
        success.hlisted(args)
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          failure(e)
      }
    }
  })
}.unhlisted
```

No `dummy` required.